# SQL syntax error near WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in this query?

```
<cfquery name="activesurveys">
      SELECT surveys.id,
             surveys.name,
             surveys.description,
      WHERE  surveys.active= 1
        AND  surveys.showinpubliclist= 1
     FROM 
             surveys
</cfquery>
<cfreturn activesurveys>
```

When I execute this code it gives this error:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE surveys.active= 1 AND surveys.showinpubliclist= 1' at line
>   4"

Comment: As an aside, placing commas *before* the column name (rather than at the end of the line) can sometimes help avoid the trailing comma problem.

Answer (score 7):

I think your query should be:

```
SELECT surveys.id,
    surveys.name,
    surveys.description
FROM surveys
WHERE surveys.active= 1
    AND surveys.showinpubliclist= 1
```

Basically, there's a `,` after the last field you want to select, which is wrong, and also there's the fact that `FROM` goes after `SELECT` and before `WHERE`...

Answer (score 5):

You need to re-order your statement a bit.  The `FROM` needs to be before the `WHERE`. And you have an extra comma after the last column in your `SELECT`. Should look something like this:

```
<cfquery name="activesurveys">
    SELECT surveys.id,
           surveys.name,
           surveys.description
    FROM  surveys
    WHERE surveys.active = 1
      AND surveys.showinpubliclist = 1
</cfquery>
<cfreturn activesurveys>
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know ColdFusion but the SQL Syntax is

```
SELECT surveys.id,
       surveys.name,
       surveys.description
FROM 
       surveys
WHERE  surveys.active= 1
       AND surveys.showinpubliclist= 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Kill the comma from the end of the last column name "surveys.description," and move the FROM statement before WHERE clause.  Like this

```
SELECT colname, colname, colname
FROM tablename

WHERE condition...
```

Comment: You're also missing the fact that the where is also before the from, that the other three posted.

Comment: ... and it's a comma, not an apostrophe.